# Reading Two Input Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have the following problem statement:

> Write a program that:
>
> 1. Reads two inputs files
> 2. Populates a two dimensional table with the integers contained in each file
> 3. Check the size of the two tables to make sure they both have the same number of rows and columns. If the tables are not the same size print an error message
> 4. Once you have read the data from each file create a third table
> 5. The elements in the third table are the result of multiplying each element in the first table by the corresponding element in the second table: `thirdTable [i] [j] = firstTable[i] [j] * secondTable[i] [j]`

I need to know how to put the second file in with my code so far.And how to write the code for table three. Here is the code for the first input file:

```
def main():
    print("Table One")
    (row, column, table) = readInput()
    return()


def readInput():
    table = []
    inputFile = open("Table 1.txt", "r")

     #  Read the first line containing the number of rows and columns
    line = inputFile.readline()

    #  split the line into two strings
    (row, column) = line.split()

    #  convert the strings into integers
    row = int(row)
    column = int(column)

    #  loop on the file container, reading each line

    for line in inputFile :
        line = line.rstrip()  #strip off the newline 
        dataList = line.split()  #  split the string into a list 
        table.append(dataList)

 #  Loop through the table and convert each element to an integer


    for i in range(row):
        for j in range (column):
            table[i] [j] = int(table[i] [j])  # convert the string to an integer
            print(" %3d" % (table[i] [j]), end = " ")
        print()

    inputFile.close()  #  close the file
    return(row, column, table)  #  return the number of rows and columns


main()
```

Comment: Is it Python? Add the language tag.

Comment: `with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:` comes to mind. Using with blocks to handle IO is mostly preferred

Comment: @TimCastelijns how do I write the code for the third table using the elements from table 1 and table 2?

Comment: I dont know, but thats not what your question is about

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `readInput` function take a parameter:

```
def readInput(filename):
    #         ^^^^^^^^ Change it here 
    table = []
    inputFile = open(filename, "r")
    #       and here ^^^^^^^^

    ... # Rest of your function
```

Then use it from `main` like this:

```
def main():

    row1, column1, table1 = readInput('Table1.txt')

    row2, column2, table2 = readInput('Table2.txt')
```

Comment: So do I need to change the rest of my code or leave it the same ?

Comment: @niya I think you only need to change the line with the `open` and the function definition.

Comment: I got this comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 3, in main
    pass
builtins.TypeError: readInput() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @niya have you changed the function definition to add a parameter?

Comment: So i keep the loop for the table the same even though each .txt contains different numbers?

Comment: @niya Since you're not using global variables, I think yes.

Comment: I kept it the same and it only prints two numbers from the table2.txt